# Keycloak 20.0.2 groups broken

Tags: keycloak

I made a group hierarchie in Keycloak:
[image]

Now I want to add user alice to the "subGroup1" of "Group1" and to the "subGroup1" of "Group2".
But after I select the first one the second is "ghosted" and I can't add it.
[image]
I think this is a bug - or is it by design?

Answer (score 0):

I updated to version 21.1.1 today and it was fixed.